# Re: Find all primes $p$ such that $\phi(x)=x^{13}$ is a homomorphism $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z \rightarrow \Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, group-homomorphism

**Note:**

This is NOT a duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2757655/find-all-primes-p-such-that-phix-x13-is-a-homomorphism-bbb-z-p-bbb-z) question.

---

**The Question:**

Find all primes $p$ such that $\phi(x)=x^{13}$ is a homomorphism $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z \rightarrow \Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$

---

**My Thoughts:**

OK, so now I understand that I am supposed to find all primes $p$ such that

$$(x+y)^{13} \equiv x^{13}+y^{13} \pmod p \quad \forall \; x,y \in \Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$$

I expanded out the binomial to get

\begin{align}
\ & \iff \sum_{k=0}^{13}C_k^{13}x^ky^{13-k} \equiv x^{13}+y^{13}\pmod p \quad \forall \; x,y \in \Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z \\
\ & \iff 13x^{12}y+78x^{11}y^2+\cdots+78x^2y^{11}+13xy^{12} \equiv 0 \pmod p \quad \forall \; x,y \in \Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z
\end{align}

Clearly, $p=13$ is a solution. But $p=2$ also works, just by inspection.

How can I prove that there is no other solution?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate to me.

Comment: I mean, that was my own question, but now I am asking something else about it

Comment: You could **edit** your previous question.

Comment: According to the guidelines, you are not really supposed to do that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

a necessary condition is that $(1+1)^{13} \equiv 1^{13} + 1^{13} \pmod{p}$ which is saying $p \mid 2^{13}-2 = 2\cdot 3^2 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 13$. You can verify which primes work (i think all do).